# Reinstall KDE from scratch on OpenSUSE

Tags: kde, opensuse, qt, kde-plasma-workspace, zypper

I have installed KDE 5 a while ago after KDE 4. It just broke. So, I am tired of trying to fix the situation here, and I just want to start over from scratch.

What I want to do is:

1. Uninstall All Qt libraries and programs (therefore, removing the KDE workspace).
2. Uninstall All KDE dependencies and libraries.
3. Install the libraries again without any bloatware (probably by adding a repository).
4. Install the KDE 5 libraries, then install Plasma (again, without bloatware).

I am using OpenSUSE Tumbleweed, and I want to use the latest stable versions of KDE and Qt.
How can I achieve that ?
Thanks, in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all openSUSE:Tumbleweed is the repo that will always contain what the openSUSE KDE packagers consider is the most stable version. There are other repositories that may contain later versions of kde but these are still under development/testing so shouldn't be considered stable.

The manual way of doing this is by looking at patterns, In yast if you go to the patterns tab, you can see a list of all the patterns, It sounds like what you want to do is remove everything listed in the 3 KDE patterns, unfortunately you will need to do this manually I believe. After that you can just reinstall plasma 5 and the software you need and you should be good.

**Update: **If you also want to remove kde config files these normally live in ~/kde4 for kde4, you can use find to look for config files with the following `find ~ -type d -iname "*kde*"` generally package managers don't track and uninstall user config files

Comment: I already know everything you stated. The Question is: How to remove **really everything** _even settings_ related to KDE ?

Comment: updated with a command to look for settings